# Phpmyadmin 4.0.5 - Error 404 - Component not found

Tags: php, iis, phpmyadmin

I have a phpmyadmin 3.5.7 already installed and running.

With version 4.0.5 I can log in, but when I click on any option I get this error:

[image]

My Setup :

- MySQL 5.1
- IIS 7.5
- PHP 5.3.3 (CGI/FastCGI)

Comment: Error 404 usually means something mentioned in the code is not found by the server!!Debug the code and try to remove/change the element for which this error is mentioned.

Comment: I found which component is not found, phpmyadmin try to open index.php but on root of my domain ex.: www.mydomain.com/mydomain/index.php ... I see nothing in phpmyadmin config maybe it's IIS related

Answer (score 1):

If you are running both phpMyAdmin versions from the same browser, there can be some mixup, so ensure you clear your browser's cache before switching phpMyAdmin version.

Comment: No, i use 2 browser for testing and anyway like you said i clear cache each time...